# MVC4 site publish to Somee

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, somee

I've created an MVC application using Visual Studio 2013 and I want to publish it using my free account of [Somee](http://www.somee.com).
They claim to support MVC 4 but I'm unable to publish.

Here's my output when trying to publish:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Somee, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Somee -> c:\users\jaime oro\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Somee\Somee\bin\Somee.dll
2>------ Publish started: Project: Somee, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Connecting to ftp://jaimeoro.somee.com...
2>Transformed Web.config using c:\users\jaime oro\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Somee\Somee\Web.Debug.config into obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.
2>Publishing folder /...
2>Unable to add 'Global.asax' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).
2>Unable to add 'packages.config' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).
2>Unable to add 'Web.config' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).
2>Unable to add folder 'bin' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "bin".
2>Unable to add folder 'Content' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "Content".
2>Unable to add folder 'Models' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "Models".
2>Unable to add folder 'Scripts' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "Scripts".
2>Unable to add folder 'Views' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "Views".
2>Site was published successfully ftp://jaimeoro.somee.com/
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Ehsan Sajjad said there was a problem with the FTP. `Site path` is required in *Somee*.

Here is the way to configure the publish tool under the connection section:

```
Publish method: FTP
Server: ftp://[YOUR USERNAME].somee.com
Site path: /www.[YOUR USERNAME].somee.com/ 
Passive mode: Checked 
User name: [YOUR USERNAME] 
Password: [YOUR PASSWORD]
```

Comment: You may try other alternative to upload your files, please just download Filezilla tools and then please upload it to your root folder.

Comment: For me it's easier to Publish from VS. With one click, the app is built and modified files are uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

It is some FTP authentication issue. See here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581719

https://serverfault.com/questions/75998/ftp-access-denied-when-uploading-to-server

Answer (score 0):

```
Publish method: FTP
Server:  ftp://domain.somee.com
Site path: Protected.domain.somee.com
Passive mode: Checked 
User name: [YOUR USERNAME] 
Password: [YOUR PASSWORD]
```

As I publish above and i succeeded..

Comment: or site path: www. your domain.somee.com

Comment: Can you advise what is the use of the "Protected Local Path"? If I publish too protected.domain.somee.com, my website doesn't work and I don't see any files in the somee File Browser.  If I publish to www.domain.somee.com, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Publish method: FTP
Server: ftp://[YOUR USERNAME].somee.com
Site path: /www.[YOUR USERNAME].somee.com/ 
Passive mode: Checked 
User name: [YOUR USERNAME] 
Password: [YOUR PASSWORD]